# Swapping two variables by creating a temporary variable

Tags: r

I am new to R programming.

I have two Variables:

```
A <- "Jack,Harris,Nelly"
B <- "Robert,Josh,Mary"
```

I need to copy all three names of vector A to Vector B and Vector B to Vector A (swapping). 
I created a third vector

```
C <- vector(“character”,length=3)
```

...and I got stuck there. Can you please help me?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to why you need to swap variables instead of just references one another, could you explain the full use case?

Comment: I also note that you specify `length = 3`: be aware that the length of both `A` and `B` = 1. A character vector of length 3 looks like this: `c("Jack", "Harris", "Nelly")`.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for your response. It's an exercise question, and it's basically asking me to swap A to B and B to A by creating an additional vector. I have no additional info. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure why you need to swap, but you can do it like this. If you explain the full reasoning maybe we can come up with a better solution to your problem. But this will work:

```
A <- "Jack,Harris,Nelly"
B <- "Robert,Josh,Mary"

C <- A
A <- B
B <- C
rm(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version using `list2env`:

```
A <- "Jack,Harris,Nelly"
B <- "Robert,Josh,Mary"

list2env(list(A=B,B=A), envir=.GlobalEnv)
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

A
#[1] "Robert,Josh,Mary"
B
#[1] "Jack,Harris,Nelly"
```